# two curves on one figure with one kept updating

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have following code which basically plot the original signal `x` on the figure, and updates the reconstructed signal `rec` iteratively.

```
plot(x); hold on

err = 100; tol = 0.1; err_vec = [];
while err > tol % iterations
    % Low-pass filter xpg
    REC = fft(rec);
    REC(M+2:N-M) = 0;
    rec = real(ifft(REC)); plot(rec, 'r*');  drawnow

    % Restore the known samples    %
    rec(ks) = y(ks);

    % Error
    err = norm(rec - x)
    err_vec = [err_vec err];
end
```

What I like is to retain `x` on the figure, and only update `rec` at each iteartion, such that I can see that `rec` is gradually approaching `x`.

However, with my current code, although `x` is retained, `rec` from each iteration simply overlaps on the figure, which is annoying. I'd like to show the `rec` from only current iteration.

How should I change my code to do that?

Comment: They've overlapping because you have `hold on`. [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) optionally returns the handle to the lineseries object, you can change the [`XData` and `YData`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html#property_d119e565678) without calling `plot` again.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the suggestion proposed by @excaza, you can try:

- call the `plot` function specifying the return value (the `handle` to the line plotted
- plot the updated curve
- call `pause` in order to "slow` the process
- call `delete` to delete the last plotted curve

A possible implementation, based on two generic curves, could be:

```
t=0:.01:2*pi;
x=sin(t);
plot(t,x)
hold on
grid on
k=0:.1:1
for i=1:length(k)
   y=sin(t);
   hp=plot(t,y*k(i),'r')
   legend('Target Curve','Approximate curve')   
   pause(.3)
   delete(hp)
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very nice        !