# Animation of 2 surface plots in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, surface

I am quite new to matlab so please forgive me if my question is a bit stupid and for my bad english.
I have 2 matrices of 10xa.  right now I set a=80 I did a surface plot which shows both matrices. The values of the elements of the matrices are dependent of a. Now I want to create an animation that shows how the surfaces are changing if a would be a vector 10:170. I hope that I can even put a regulator in the figure so I can set a to a certain value.

Comment: You can get some ideas from the [answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49222343/4806927). Try replacing the call to `plot` with `surf` or with the function you use to plot the surface. Basically you need: a `loop`, a call to `pause` and to delete the plotted surfaces after the call to `pause` (use `delete` to delete the surfaces).

Comment: It is much faster to update the data of the graphical object rather than to delete and re-create it inside of the loop.   There is a example of this in Matlab's documentation:  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/animating-a-surface.html

Comment: @AeroEngy while it might be right when you want simply to update a plot, when it coms to create an "animation", the speed of the plotting seens, to me, less relevant, since you actually "need" to slow down the sequence of plots.